# How Do I make the Install4j IDE to upgrade to Java7 instead of Java6

Tags: install4j

I have upgraded to `Java7` recently.
I had my install4j  Project file in `Java6`.
Now in the Install4j IDE,  I go to Media wizard and download  1.7 JRE's and select them for Windows.  (I have window 7 64 bit.)

But When I go the Installer tab in IDE , where for some of the screens I have my custom code which is compiled in Java7.
It gives an error for the IDE  java version  lower than the compiled version(for those class files).

The Common Location where is the JRE for 1.6 was downloaded  `C:\Program Files\Common Files\i4j_jres`

But the JREs  for 1.7 somehow  are never downloaded in the common location.

How Do I make the Install4j IDE to upgrade to Java7 instead of Java6.

Thanks
Sony

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem as you, so we just swapped out install4j's built-in JRE with the one we used to compile our custom code.

i.e. - replace "C:\Program Files\install4j5\jre" with the jre you use to build your custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

Under General Settings->Java version, change the minimum version to 1.7

Comment: @Sony I think I misunderstood your question, see my edited answer

Comment: Hi, I have tried making the minimum version to 1.7 .but still the issue exists. I am using Install4j version 4.2.8 . If I remove the 1.6 jre's from the location C:\Program Files\Common Files\i4j_jres , I cannot open the install4file project file also.I get the error message no "JVM found on your system, Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME ...." .